# Spacemacs is not work with daemon mode

Tags: emacs

I started Spacemacs and tried to run

```
emacs --daemon
```

to touch a server. But it's not work.
This is messages.

```
>emacs --daemon
Loading c:/Tools/emacs/.spacemacs.d/init.el (source)...
Loading c:/Tools/emacs/.spacemacs.d/init.el (source)...done
(Spacemacs) Warning: More than one init function found for package symbol-overlay. Previous owner was spacemacs-navigation, replacing it with layer zilongshanren-misc.
Auto-evilification could not remap these functions in map ?dired-mode-map?:
   - ?dired-do-chgrp? originally mapped on ?G?
~/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/progmodes/cc-align.elc:Warning: reference to free
    variable ?langelem?
Spacemacs is ready.
Loading c:/Tools/emacs/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf...
Loading c:/Tools/emacs/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf...done
Skipping check for new version (reason: dotfile)
```

Emacs will stuck here every time, and few minutes later, this message shows up.

```
Buffer recentf modified; kill anyway? (y or n) Buffer recentf modified; kill anyway? (y or n)
```

Program will stuck here even I press 'y' or 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to start spacemacs before** :

```
emacs --daemon
```

launches a background server that you need to access afterwards with a client using this command :

```
emacsclient <filenane>
```

For further information please visit https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient

---

**If you have already started the GUI Spacemacs app:**

You need to run the command inside Spacemacs - Press `M-:` (`Alt` + `:`) and

```
(server-start)
```

and then `emacsclient <filename>` from a terminal.